# Silm V3 and Doctrine Validator annotation

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, annotations, slim

I'm using Slim Framework with Doctrine.
    I Follow this link http://blog.sub85.com/slim-3-with-doctrine-2.html and it's works

Now I Want to add `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints` and I Install it by composer.

I added an assert like

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   * @Assert\NotBlank()
   */
  protected $foo;
```

But I Have this error
The annotation `"@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" .... does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.`

I tried also to use

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
```

in index.php

my libraries are:

```
"symfony/validator": "^3.1"
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"slim/slim": "^3.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;` ?

or

Add this on your composer.json : [doctrine/common](https://github.com/doctrine/common)

Documentation : [docs.doctrine-project.org](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html)